# Multiple Threading is good to use in asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I am using Thread for background process in asp.net web application.

Now to the question. Are there any reasons for me not to use multiple threads in a web application? Or do it exist specific guidelines for usage of multiple threads in a web application?

Comment: too vague, really depends on the structure of your web application

Comment: ohk. but in general application, is it good to use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS is a multi-threaded server. In general, its good to let IIS worry about the threads.

Know that a background process thread in IIS would be subject to a lot of constraints.
It can live only as long as your request thread, and IIS times these out.

Long running tasks are best pushed out of IIS to

- A service process
- A WCF based web service
- A SQL server job

IIS is not designed for long running jobs. It is designed to process requests quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do multithreading in ASP.NET, although the need should be very
rare since each page request is executed on a separate thread anyway. I agree that the need will rarely come up. One such need is if several
operations need to take place, and each one might take a bit of time. In
that case, all four could be started on separate threads, and the page could
return after all four threads complete their work. Of course, designing a
page like that would require more than intermediate skill with ASP.NET.